# What's the purpose of Laravel's second app.css file?

Tags: php, css, laravel, npm, npm-run

I'm learning Laravel 8, and I'm confused as to what the purpose of `Resources\css\app.css` is. Everything else in the Resources folder seems to have a purpose, but not only is the `app.css` file here empty, adding anything to it and then compiling with `npm run dev` also does nothing.

If all custom CSS that I use with Laravel needs to be placed in `public\css` anyway, which is how I understand Laravel is supposed to work, what's the purpose of `Resources\css\app.css`?

Comment: You mean `resources/css/app.css`? Why "_second app.css_"? That's the one that gets compiled to `public/css/app.css` - as stated in `webpack.mix.js`

Comment: @brombeer Apologies, fixed. Second because it feels useless given that most guides state to place custom code in `public/css`. If what you're saying is the case, does this mean my own `resources/css/app.css` file shouldn't be empty? Or that, if I do add code to it and compile, that code should end up in the `public/app.css` file? So far none of these appear to be the case in my installation, although in the latter case maybe I was just looking for the wrong thing.

Comment: Yes `resoures/css/app.css` is initially empty and `public/css/app.css` doesn't exist. After adding some css to `resoures/css/app.css` and `npm run dev` the new contents are available in `public/css/app.css`

Comment: @brombeer Thanks for the clarifications. If you're willing to add that as an answer I'd be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should write your CSS to the file within resources\css\app.css.

Using Laravel Mix may then compile it, compress it and maybe do additional steps like purging unused CSS classes (if you‘d use something like TailwindCSS).
This process will replace the file in public\css, so don’t write your styles directly to this file.